# Closure Compiler RESTFul API output_info Parameter

Tags: wordpress, google-closure-compiler

I'm using the Google Closure Compiler RESTFul API with WordPress.
The request is created using `wp_remote_post()` and so far everything went okay.

What I want to know is how to get the API to not only return the compiled code, but also the warnings, errors and statistics.

Supplying `'output_info' => array( 'compiled_code', 'warnings', 'errors', 'statistics' )` in the `body` parameter seems not to work and the API returns errors. Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Just looked around and found out that Closure Compiler accepts `output_info` parameter multiple times. This is not possible with the `WP_Http` API without some modifications.

So I looked at the source of `WP_Http` and did the following, now it's working :)

```
// Default request data
$request_data = array(
    'output_info' => array( 'compiled_code', 'warnings', 'errors', 'statistics' ), 
    'output_format' => 'json'
);
$request_data = array_merge( $request_data, $args, compact( 'js_code' ) );

// Process the request body manually to make same named parameters possible
$body = http_build_query( $request_data, null, '&' );
$body = preg_replace( '/output_info%5B\d+%5D=/', 'output_info=', $body );

// Initiate request
$response = wp_remote_post( CLOSURE_COMPILER_URL, array(
    'sslverify' => false, 
    'timeout' => 10, 
    'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=' . get_option( 'blog_charset' )
    ), 
    'body' => $body
));
```